# R stops script after shiny app without error

Tags: r, windows, shiny, osx-yosemite

This is my first time posting a question here, so forgive me if I am overly vague or unclear. I am running a script in R that begins with a shiny app, and when using Windows this script runs flawlessly. However, when on a Mac, the script seems to catch at certain commands after the shiny app. Here's a minimal example of my script. I included the complete shiny app in case it is relevant.

```
library(shiny)
master_metatable=read.csv('metadata.csv')

#begin shiny app
select_tables=runApp(list(
  ui=fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Data Repository v0.01"),
    fluidRow(
      column(3,
             checkboxGroupInput("phase_selection",
                     label = "Choose Phase",
                     choices = c("Phase I","Phase II","Phase III"),
                     selected = "Phase I")),

      column(3,
             uiOutput("ui")),

      column(3,
             actionButton("done","Done"))

    )
  ),
  server=function(input,output){
    output$ui=renderUI({
      tables=unique(master_metatable$measure[which(master_metatable$cohort==input$phase_selection)])
      checkboxGroupInput("table_selection",
                     label = "Tables",
                     tables)
    })

    output$text1=renderText({
     paste0("You have selected ",input$table_selection)
    })


    observeEvent(input$done, stopApp(list(input$phase_selection,
                                                 input$table_selection)))
  }

))
#end shiny app


#test print 1
print("test1")

testcsv=read.csv('metadata.cv')

#test print 2
print("test2")


library(tcltk)
filepath=tk_choose.dir()
```

...etc

So for example, when I run this script on my Mac, it completes the shiny app, prints 'test1', then begins to read in testcsv but stops. It does not produce an error or warning message or even give a '+' indicating I left out a ')' or something. It just stops, does not read in the table, and never continues with the rest of the script. It is not frozen either, it just acts like it got to the end of the script.  Note that this is the same csv I imported at the top of the script, so there is nothing wrong with my syntax or the csv file. HOWEVER, if I only run the shiny app part of the script first, then run the rest of the script, everything works flawlessly! In other words, if I run the whole script all at once, it catches, but if I just highlight the shiny app and run it, then highlight everything else and run it, it works. Again, this anomaly only happens on Macs (I tried two Macs both running Yosemite), and the script works perfectly on Windows (both 64bit and 32bit).

Also, every now and then on my Mac when running the whole script, it will successfully run the app AND read in the csv, but will catch on something else later in the script. It only seems to catch on commands related to the environment (i.e. read.csv, read.table, tk_choose.dir). It never has any problems with basic processing commands. Once it even completed the whole script without problem, but the next time I ran it, it caught on read.csv again.

I also don't think this problem is related to processing limitations of my machine, as I have run much more demanding scripts in R on my computer without problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: How are you running that script? Are you using RStudio?

Comment: Yes, I am using R studio
R version 3.2.4 (2016-03-10)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.10.5 (Yosemite)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the answer on a [GitHub forum](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/869). It has to do with the viewer pane in RStudio. To use on Macs, I added 'options(shiny.launch.browser = TRUE)' to the beginning of my script so it uses my computer's default web browser as a viewer pane instead of R's.